# In pytorch what is ([3,128,128]) and just(3,128,128)

Tags: computer-vision, pytorch

I'm so confused about the image shape. 
I just read the image and it shape with

> img[0].shape = ([3,128,128])

what is  ([3,128,128]) and (3,128,128)? 
How can I convert it?

trying to reshpae the

```
img.shape = ([3,128,128]) 
img = cv2.resize(img,(32,32))
iamge_shape->torch.Size([1, 3, 128, 128])
```

> following error
>
> ```
> img = cv2.resize(img,(32,32)) TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument '%s'
> ```

Comment: The surrounding parenthesis on first expression aren't actually doing anything. Also what does this have to do with pytorch or computer vision?

Answer (score 0):

([3,128,128]) is a list and (3,128,128) is a tuple. When you are viewing a shape of an image 3 denotes the dimension of the array and 128,128 is the number of rows and columns. If I consider you have used opencv to read the image then it would be an numpy array. Please specify exactly what the problem is.